# How do I build a variable from a character repeated N number of times, in Lua?

Tags: variables, lua, repeat

I have an input value of N.

I want to turn that into a variable consisting of N characters.

for example, if N = 12, and I'm repeating the character "H", the value of the created variable should look like this: "HHHHHHHHHHHH"

I need it to be a variable, because I intend to use it in a few other places.

I am completely new to Lua, by the way. I just started a few days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [string.rep](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.rep).

For example:

```
local result = string.rep("H", 12)
print(result) -- prints "HHHHHHHHHHHH"
```

Comment: Is the output of the print function considered a variable?

Comment: No - you would have to put it in a variable yourself. The print function just gives you a way to actually see the output. I'll edit my answer slightly to show you how to use a variable.

Comment: Okay. What I am looking for is something that will output a variable.

Comment: I appreciate the help.

If I don't include the print function, how do I get from ( local result = string.rep("H", N) ) to a variable I can further manipulate?

Comment: Ah. wait. Looks like I have what I need from string.rep(). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The datatype string has a metatable with all string functions attached as methods in `__index`.

Therefore you also can do...

```
local str, N = "H", 12
str = str:rep(N)
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `("H"):rep(12)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `load()` function to do it.

```
load(string.format("%s=4711", string.rep("H", 12)))()

print(HHHHHHHHHHHH)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think the OP wanted the _value_ of the variable to be "HHHHHHHHHHHH". This makes the _name_ of the variable "HHHHHHHHHHHH".